# What happens to gravity and spacetime when mass turns to energy?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, mass-energy

What will happen to the distorted space and time around a mass when it is converted into energy?

Will it go back to its original configuration (i.e. with $0$ gravity)?
Or does space time oscillate? Or is there something else that happens?

Comment: According to relativity theory, mass cannot really convert to energy. The well-known formula $E = mc^2$ says that mass and energy are the same thing.

Comment: So you want to say that energy also distort space and time.

Comment: Correct. In the [Einstein field equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Mathematical_form) the tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ contains the energy and momentum density which might have its origin not only in matter ("mass") but also in other types of energy.

Comment: There is no simple answer, because quantum mechanics is not compatible with general relativity. It depends on the details. If the released energy is perfectly contained, then almost nothing may happen, because the gravitational equations include the stress-energy tensor. However, if you convert a planet to a burst of light, you would need to know the gravitational field of each photon. The gravity of a photon is not static,  it is a gravitational wave emitted from the source. The full treatment is a subject of quantum gravity that has not been developed. So there is no simple answer.

Comment: Hint: The source for gravity is energy rather than mass.

Comment: @md2perpe - it's not the same but equivalent, but regarding that energy also bends spacetime you're right

Comment: @Yukterez. How can you differ between two things when they are equivalent?

Comment: By the conversion factor c². Energy is not mass, it is mass times c² plus kinetic and potential components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this can get a bit tricky if I just throw the full science at you outright, so what I'm going to do is start with a very unrealistic physical situation and then move on to full realism. So just bear with me.

**Unrealistic:** let's suppose you took a lump of matter and converted it all into light and that you have a system of magic mirrors (that's the technical term) to bounce that light around and effectively keep it contained to the same volume as the original mass. So far so good? Great. Now it's boring math time:

The mass density of matter is simple to write down. Let's call it $\rho$. If we change this to pure energy, then we can write down the energy density:

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2c^2}\left(\epsilon_0E^2+{1\over{\mu_0}}B^2\right)$$

The terms in this equation correspond to the energy density of the electric and magnetic fields ($E$ and $B$ respectively) in EM waves and the $1\over{c^2}$ out front converts energy to mass to make the equation valid.

Why did I just tell you that? Am I that boring? Am I going mad? Is it actually useful? The answer is both.

In General Relativity (GR), we describe gravity pretty well using the Einstein Field Equations. I won't bore you with the description of those. Short story is that one side describes gravity warping spacetime and the other side describes all things that generate gravity (yeah, that's an interpretation. Sue me if you don't like it). On the latter side, we have something called the [Stress-Energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). In this tensor, one of the terms represents the sum Energy density of matter and radiation. The matter component is just $\rho$ and the radiation component is the right side of the above equation. Why is this important? Well, if you have only a lump of mass at first and then change it to radiation, the equality above means that the amount of gravity generated doesn't change! (cue gasp of astonishment)

So if you could contain the energy, nothing would change with the gravity.

**Realistic:** So you have a lump of matter and convert it to energy. Well, being massless, energy has this weird preference of travelling as fast as it can (I know, what a loser). It's also notoriously hard to fully contain. So, unless the object you convert to energy was a black hole, odds are high that the energy will escape your system. What does this mean for the gravity? To an observer outside the light cone, nothing. Mind you, they won't observe the mass being gone either so it's just a regular Tuesday for them. To you, the mass and/or energy will no longer be where it was. In fact, if you're not destroyed by the massive energy release during the conversion, you'll probably be inside of a spherical shell of light. And we all know that inside a spherical shell there's no gravitational force.

So as your light moves outwards, what moves with it is a gravity wave (a rather outstanding one at that). Ahead of the wave, normal gravity; behind the wave, zero gravity.

**Doomsday device:** Okay, you accept everything so far. Let's say you can convert the mass to energy and, instead of radiation outwards, you can have it all point inwards towards the center of the formerly-existing mass. For a sufficiently massive object, you could get enough photons compressed into a small enough volume (no smaller than the largest photon wavelength across) that it would create a black hole. Once done, this black hole would be fixed (barring evaporation) and could continue to destroy anything nearby (try this at parties to amuse your friends!). It's essentially the ultimate doomsday weapon. No longer do you have to compress the matter itself (durn fermions make that annoying), you can just convert it to energy and let it compress itself. Tada! Instant black hole to engulf anyone foolish enough to question your authority.

Comment: There's no gravitational wave (freely propagating mode of the gravitational field) in your light-shell example, just an electromagnetic wave. It's similar to an expanding spherical shell of charge in electromagnetism (without gravity). The field does change at the shell but that's due to the local presence of charge. It's not an independently propagating reconfiguration of the far field.

Comment: @benrg would you have been happier if I called it a wavefront? I thought it was obvious that is what I meant. And yes, there absolutely must be one

Answer (score 1):

To answer this, lets use a single atom as an example. Essentially, the energy contained in that atom (bonds between the sub-atomic particles in the atoms nucleus) radiates away at the speed of light away when released, mostly in the form of Gamma radiation. the gravitational field would radiate out in exactly the same way, since mass is essentially energy stored in the bonds between the particles that make up the nucleus of the atom.

This means the mass really was just stored energy, which is released when those bonds break. It would cause a ripple in the gravitational field. Of course, there being nothing were the atom used to be, there's nothing to attract anything there.

Comment: What is the meaning of "gravitational ripple" here? A gravitational wave ??

Comment: Basically like a wave without a trough behind it, barring any oscillations due to field interactions. imagine adding a drop of water to the middle of a lake - the surface height would increase slightly, propagating at the speed of the wave.

Comment: So an atomic bomb can produce a gravitational wave.??

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to convert mass into energy. The mass of a star e.g. decreases slowly due to nuclear fusion processes. In this case energy is radiated away which corresponds to a slight decrease of mass. As the mass of the star remains spherical symmetric during this process, so does its gravitational field and thus the spacetime around the star will not be distorted.

The complete conversion of mass into energy is possible by particle-antiparticle annihilation. Perform this process in a ideal box (withstanding the heat) the weight of the box will not change and neither does the spacetime.

Distortions of spacetime are caused by asymmetric processes (more technically if the mass quadrupole moment of a system changes over time) as during the merger of black holes, supernovae explosions and the like.